# Include not available in inherited repostory

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a repository like:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity
{
    protected readonly IContext _db;

    public Repository(IContext context)
    {
        _db = context;
    }

   ...
}
```

Within methods in this class I can write statements with includes like:

```
var regionalAdmins = _db.Users.Include("Areas");
```

So then I wrote a repository which inherits from that one:

```
public class AreaRepository : Repository<Area>
{
    public AreaRepository(IContext context) : base (context)
    {
    }

    public new IEnumerable<Area> GetAreas()
    {
        return _db.Users.Include("Areas");
    }
}
```

At this level though I get the error:

> System.Data.Entity.IDbSet' does not contain a definition
>   for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet' could be
>   found

Why would this be happening? I have the same context it just coming from the parent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Include`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696395%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) is an extension method declared in [`System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696544%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). You're probably missing a `using` clause for the `System.Data.Entity` namespace.